# Swing Formatting with JTextField & BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, formatting, jtextfield

```
JTextField area2 = new JTextField();
JTextField searchtext=new JTextField();
JPanel mainframe = new JPanel();
JButton searchbutton=new JButton("Submit");
JButton registerbutton=new JButton("Login/Register");

mainframe.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainframe, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
JPanel p4 = new JPanel();

p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 
p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
p4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p4, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("FLIGHT LISTINGS"));
p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("SEARCH"));
p3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 
p3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("User Account"));
p3.add(registerbutton);
p2.add(searchtext);
p2.add(searchbutton);

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("map.jpg"); 
JLabel thumb = new JLabel();
thumb.setIcon(icon);
p4.add(thumb);

mainframe.add(p3);
mainframe.add(p4);
mainframe.add(p2);
mainframe.add(p1);
this.add(mainframe);
```

this is my code, and the result seems to always give me a gross-looking output. i would much rather have my JTextField be only 1 line in height instead of so fat. would anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

this is the devastating result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXD73.jpg

Answer (score 2):

```
mainframe.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainframe, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

A BoxLayout will grow components based on the available space in the frame. So if your text field is growing to an unreasonable size that means you are using:

```
frame.setSize(...);
```

and are giving your frame some random size that is not appropriate for the components you added to the frame.

Instead you should be using:

```
frame.pack();
```

and all the components will be displayed at their preferred sizes.

Let the layout managers to their jobs and don't assign sizes to components.

Comment: @HuangLee You need to `pack()` the `JFrame`.

Comment: when i do that, only the menu remains and everything (the whole frame) is minimized and i have to expand it by dragging the window open

Comment: @HuangLee, You need to add all the components to the frame, then you invoke `frame.pack(), frame.setVisible(true);`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for working examples. Download the demo code and then modify the code for your requirement. The demo code is better structured than your code. Learn from the working example.

Comment: @HuangLee and don't forget to "accept" the answer when the suggestion works. I notice that you haven't "accepted" any answers from your previous questions.

Comment: i did what you told me though, i did pack then this.setVisible(true) and i get an image that looks like this: http://imgur.com/XDEbTPg (this is with and without setvisible afterwards). and yes, i packed LAST after i added all components, then afterwards i set it to visible. either way, this is the result.

Comment: @HuangLee,  `Still waiting for you tot "accepted" answers from your other questions`. Did you download the demo from the tutorial??? Did it work??? So how is your code different???. I suggest you start with the working demo code from the tutorial because the code will be properly structured. Then you make changes one at a time. First add your "Login Panel" and get it to display properly. Then add the map. If you need more help post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.